# How to create browser independent cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies

- I am trying to build a voting system where user can vote without signing up on the site
- The cookies are dependent on browser, so people can vote more than once if they use different browsers(I want to stop them doing that)(I don't want any bias)
- I read [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) is something that I can use. The problem that I saw with this is that the call seems asynchronous. for example

I do the following

```
 var ec = new evercookie
 ec.get("id", function(value) { 
        alert("Cookie value is " + value);
        if (value != null) {
           alert('cookie already set, returning');
           return;
        }
        ec.set("id", "12345");
        alert('cookie saved');
 });
```

When I use this code, it first sets the cookie, refreshes the page and then returns the value, so I see in following order

```
cookie saved
cookie already set, returning
```

Can someone please help me to setup browser-independent cookies?

Thank you

Comment: There is a reason why signing up exists.... The problem you are having it exactly THAT

Comment: If somebody is determined to vote more than once they will find a way. Even with one browser users can delete cookies. Even with site login required people might create multiple accounts.

Comment: Of just go to another computer, or another profile on the same computer.  There are lots of ways around this issue when using any form of client storage.  Only authenticated user access to server storage has a chance at solving this problem and even then you have to prevent the user from creating multiple accounts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should not use that library. It puts a lot of trash in your visitors browser, is very unstable (the page crashes for me). I think it exists to state a case and not to be used in a production environment.

Also, it can be worked around easily by just not using a browser, but a script (wget, etc.) instead. An attacker can vote hundrets of times in a short period like that.

You should save votes by IP-address in a database and allow only 1 vote per day or so. That's the most common tradeoff between security and usability.

Comment: how does it handles the case of DHCP configured machines?

Comment: @daydreamer If you are talking about dynamic IP-addresses, these people can vote as often as their ISP gives them a new IP-address once they restart their router - which is somewhat troublesome. Other than that, everybody will be able to vote once a day. This is the best result you will get - and it is much better than using (ever-)cookies.

Answer (score 8):

You can't do this with just cookies.

Cookies are stored *per-browser* (and sometimes even *per-mode* or *per-session*) and, in any case, can be *cleared* by the user at whim.

Now, [evercookie](http://samy.pl/evercookie/) tries to get about this, by storing the data in *many* different ways, in the hope that not all of them are cleared [simultaneously]. ***These methods employeed, however, are still generally confined to a given browser/profile*** and depend upon which additional mechanisms can be employeed. (*EC can also be bypassed simply by disabling JavaScript, adjusting the [cookie or in-flight] values with a debugging tool, or using a non-browser to initiate requests.*)

Anyway, when using the EC approach (it may have limited success, depending upon demographic, but it is *far from* being "hackproof"), simply set a [large] "random value" if no value is set, and always send that value to the server. (There really is no point requiring a nonce from the server as the server has no way to verify the original request was not "duplicate", which is sort of a catch-22.)

Happy coding.

Comment: `in the hope that not all of them are cleared` Yes evercookie set a lot of cookies in different ways but actually evercookie checks if one cookie was deleted and restore it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description of what you are attempting to accomplish, cookies would be a very, very poor choice. Not even evercookie would be browser independent. And, once a user clears their cookies, evercookie is useless.

Storing the ip address server side is the closest thing available to getting what you are looking for. But even that is fraught with challenges. Many corporate IT departments will set things up so that all requests coming from their network will have the same outward ip. In this case, even if there are thousands of employees, each with their own computer, once one person on that network submits a vote, any other user on the same network would be blocked from doing so. Same applies to any household with an ISP.

The bottom line is that what you're looking for simply goes against the very core architecture of the Internet.